# Oracle apex page item properties

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

in oracle apex I want to change some properties of page  ( like security scheme etc.) but I want to do it on some custom form not from shared component. I cant find any package or function to do it. It is autonomus cloud database so I cant change the table directly because it is forbidden in cloud version. Anyone knows how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an existing APEX page and are trying to change its definition? I don't think there is any API to change the definition of a page like that. You have to go through the APEX Designer.

Comment: It is possible with APEX designer and shared components but I want customer to change some attributes   like authorization of page on custom admin panel . Just like user management through API I thought that there is something for page management.